# Как в git под windows сравнить 2 версии файла в одной ветке?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

Добрый день. Прошу помощи.
Как сравнить 2 коммита одного файла в визуальном инструменте, типа WinMerge?

Answer (score 2):

просто сравнить две версии файла

```
git diff <sha1_1> <sha1_2> -- filename
```

два минуса подсказывают гиту, что дальше именно имя файла, а не параметры. ha1_1 и sha1_2 - хеши коммитов, в которых нужно сравнивать. Можно и имена веток/тегов писать.

если нужно открыть в сторонней утилите, то используется другая команда - difftool. Но ей нужно указать "инструмент".

```
git difftool -t winmerge <sha1_1> <sha1_2> -- filename
```

вполне возможно, что его не найдет. Тогда нужно winmerge прописать  в пути поиска. Либо правильно настроить [gitconfig](https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/6158524).

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. 
Вот такой синтаксис работает (WinMerge прописан в .gitconfig):
git difftool 5fc639348d71eb374d97be157fa44cb6b736b586 c332
baa4b5e0d1824f2cbfbb09934ecc92c2f369 -- "имя_файла_кириллица.txt"